# getting an interval of a vector

Tags: vector, scheme

I want to take an interval of a vector in Scheme. I know there is a procedure named `vector->values`, but seems like it returns each element separately, while I want to get the result as a vector. How can I achieve this?

```
> (vector->values (vector 1 2 3 4 5) 0 3)
1
2
3
```

while I need:

```
#(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PLT, you have a few easy ways to get this:

```
(define (subvector v start end)
  (list->vector (for/list ([i (in-vector v start end)]) i)))

(define (subvector v start end)
  (build-vector (- end start) (lambda (i) (vector-ref v (+ i start)))))

(define (subvector v start end)
  (define new (make-vector (- end start)))
  (vector-copy! new 0 v start end)
  new)
```

The last one is probably going to be the fastest.  The reason that there is no such operation that is built-in is that people usually don't do that.  When you're dealing with vectors in Scheme, you're usually doing so because you want to optimize something so returning a vector and a range instead of allocating a new one is more common.

(And if you think that this is useful, please suggest it on the PLT mailing list.)

Comment: This is 100 times better than my solution.

Comment: Looks like PLT specific. How about a portable Scheme version?

Comment: Rainer, if you care about it, feel free to make it yourself.  I'll just ignore the flame attempts and get real work done instead.

Comment: I'll wait for your portable CL GUI system, or thread or whatever.
All are portable part of PLT, the language I'm programming in.

Comment: No problem all of them are portable in LispWorks. Getting sub sequences is more basic, and really should be part of a standard Scheme library. Symptomatic that three answers fail to provide a portable solution. A 'standard lib' would be useful. Maybe there is even a SRFI for it. Why drag people to a specific Scheme, when such basic stuff like sub vectors should be there?

Comment: "Scheme" is as much of a myth for real programming tasks as "Common Lisp" is.  I could have written a portable version, I could have even used a srfi as grettke did -- but like I said, I prefer to get work done instead.

Comment: Just an update from the future: `vector-copy` now takes optional start and end indices, so you can use it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The Scheme R6RS standard has *make-vector*, *vector-ref*, *vector-set!* and *vector-length*. With that you can write your own function *subvector*, which does not seem to be part of R6RS (!). Some Scheme implementation have something like *subvector* already.

You can also switch to Common Lisp, which provides the function SUBSEQ in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a portable [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/) version using [SRFI 43](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html):

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base)
        (prefix (srfi :43) srfi/43:))

(srfi/43:vector-copy (vector 1 2 3 4 5) 0 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang scheme
(define (my-vector-value v l h c)
  (if (and (>= c l) (< c h))
      (cons (first v) (my-vector-value (rest v) l h (add1 c)))
      empty))

(list->vector (my-vector-value (vector->list (vector 1 2 3 4 5)) 0 3 0))
```

Ghetto?  Yes, very.  But it only took two minutes to write and gets the job done.

(I find it's generally easier to play with lists in Scheme)

Comment: Looks like *add1* and *empty* are not in the Scheme standard.

Answer (score 0):

you want [`subvector`](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2003/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_9.html#SEC86):

```
(subvector (vector 1 2 3 4 5) 0 3)
```

Comment: seems like drscheme doesn't have the procedure subvector :(

Comment: MIT Scheme, but not in the Scheme standard.